# About normal closure a subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ where $\{H_i\mid i=1..,n\}$ is the set of all conjugate of $H$.

Then $$H^G=H_1.H_2...H_n$$ where $H^G$ denotes the normal closure of $H$.

This is an exercise from The Theory of Finite Groups by Kurzweil$(1.1.13)$.

Since this exercise lies in first cheapter, I had thought that it can be proven in a elemantary way, yet I could not do it.

Comment: What's the exercise? Prove that statement?

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg: Yes, this is the exercise.

Comment: The difficult part for me is showing right-hand side is a group, which I could not see a way to do it.

Comment: You can prove it by repeated use of the identity $ba = a(b^{-1}ab)$. In a product of elements from the groups $H_i$, use it to move all terms in $H_1$ to the left, then all terms in $H_2$ to their place, etc.

Comment: @DerekHolt:  I forgot to write thanks. Thank you.